# Would it be possible to add flagging/voting to "Low Quality Answers" review queue

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, low-quality-posts

In Low Quality Answers queue, it is only possible to edit the answer to make it look better and flag it for deletion with pre-defined reasons. If something else is needed with the answer (i.e. flag it as spam or vote it), it is not possible. Would it be possible to add this functionality?

Comment: We might want to restrict some of the flagging options, since "not an answer" and "low quality" flags feed right back into the queue and could be abused for farming helpful flags. I can see allowing spam and offensive flags, since those could bring spammers and trolls to the attention of moderators for destruction.

Comment: @BradLarson Agreed, that makes sense. Specific case I was talking about was actually a question posted as an answer, with comment like "This doesn't work for me for downloading MP3s from _url_ and _url_, these are free MP3 downloading sites", so easily flaggable as "different question as an answer", but kind of advertising as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Flagging - with, as Brad notes, a limited subset of options - might make sense. Start a list of reasons to flag for posts you come across.

Voting is not gonna happen. Don't get me wrong: voting is good. But if you want to vote, click through and vote on the main question page, where you can also see the full set of answers, related questions, flag whatever needs to be flagged *however* it needs to be flagged, etc.

I've explained why voting has been omitted here [elsewhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140405/why-is-voting-removed-from-new-review-system/141145#141145), but here's a simple way to think about it:

#### The full question page

[image: a wide variety of tools]

#### Review

[image: A small variety of hammers]

Comment: I failed a LQ-queue audit (see my related question) because I was trying to find where to flag-as-spam in the review UI... so I think there's definitely a place for the limited flagging option in the review queue.

Comment: since LQR audits are always spam, there really should be a flagging option in the queue...

Comment: "Start a list of reasons to flag for posts you come across." Here you go, a complete list: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191860/include-the-option-to-flag-posts-as-spam-in-the-low-quality-queue

Comment: damn those hammers are worn out.

Comment: An an interesting twist of fate, [the *exact opposite* is currently in effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ol4AN.png) in the LQA queue.

Comment: That's... Heh... Just a bit underbaked, @zcoop98 - here's a fun side effect: if you upvote a 0-scored answer and then try to submit a delete review, it'll error out. Which is (strictly speaking) correct, but... Probably shouldn't be able to invalidate a review task from within the review UI!