# Should the Low Quality queue have "Flag this post" available?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5046839

I wanted to Flag as spam, didn't see a way, clicked edit => failed review. I suspect my review stats are doing fine, but the disposition of that answer as anything but spam seems inappropriate.

Should there be a "Flag this post" outcome in reviews to mark subtle spam that's in the LQ queue?

Comment: Is there no flag link in the VLQ queue? (Used my VLQ reviews today so can't check.. but I'd imagine there is)

Comment: There is no flag link.

Comment: Is the focus of the question how the post should have been flagged in the first place or whether a "Flag this Post" button be added to the low quality queue?

Comment: I have both questions, @Anonymous. I think the better outcome is "Flag this Post" feature request for LQ queue, and will edit to focus on that.

Comment: AFAIK spam flags put the post into the VLQ queue though, and I think the audits are regularly spam.

Comment: So VLQ reviews that are spam should be reviewed as "not an answer" despite the automatic comment language not speaking to spam?

Comment: (gah annoying that I can't check the queue), but IIRC the appropriate action is to "recommend deletion", if a post is spam theres no need to leave one of the canned NAA comments. OK you may have thought the best action was to flag, and were confused with the options presented to you. But what are you going to do next time you see spam (audit or real) in the VLQ queue? edit? or recommend deletion? obviously you'll do the latter, so I don't see this as much of a problem.

Comment: Ah. I would think spam warranted special flagging so we could fry the spammer, but I'm not that meta-participating so that attitude may be a relic of being very lurker-ish.

Comment: You might be right actually. Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252768/would-it-be-possible-to-add-flagging-voting-to-low-quality-answers-review-queu