# What am I supposed to do with a piece of spam that I review in the Low Quality queue?

Tags: support, review-queues, flags, low-quality-posts, spam

While reviewing in the Low Quality Posts queue I was presented with [an answer that looked](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5999258) like it would be [delicious grilled with a slice of pineapple](http://www.spam.com/recipes/Hawaiian-SPAMBURGER-Hamburger):

[image]

I wasn't too sure what to do with this in the queue, since [there's no flagging option](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252768/would-it-be-possible-to-add-flagging-voting-to-low-quality-answers-review-queu).

What I ended up doing was going to the post outside the queue, flagging it as spam, and then coming back and recommending deletion.

Is that the intended way to handle such a situation, or should I have only done one or the other?

This is doubly confusing given the [use of previously-identified spam as audits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6007703). That implies that *only* clicking Delete in the queue would be correct, since if I go visit the post, there's no possible way I'm going to fail the audit (by pressing "Looks Good"), and if I hit "Skip", the audit is defeated -- it was a waste of time for me and the system.

On the other hand, the fact that [spam flags are apparently dismissed when a post is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175420/) suggests that the correct action would be to flag the post but "Skip" in the queue -- ensuring that the spam-identification process can be completed.

Comment: Interesting, do spam flags push posts into the Low Quality Queue? I'm guessing no, but why is there no "This is spam" option when recommending deletion. If this is deleted with the "No comment needed" option, wouldn't that prevent the account being nuked from orbit asap?

Comment: I normally go to the post and specifically flag as spam. The thinking behind it is that I want to give moderators a chance to take more drastic action if they find it necessary (e.g. by giving users a timeout if it's blatant). But I'm looking forward to a more official response, because it's not entirely clear.

Comment: Related feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191860/include-the-option-to-flag-posts-as-spam-in-the-low-quality-queue

Comment: Another related feature request: [Don't use spam post as audits in the low quality review queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238647)

Comment: The burger looks tasty, mmmmm

Comment: I am guessing that the reason there is no spam option in the LQRQ is because it would be mis-used way too often. Many answers technically answer the question of "*is there a library/tool/resource I can use*", which are pretty much just link only and can be deleted. However, these often look like possible spam, but in most cases shouldn't be treated as such since we have to assume the answerer had good intent of providing the link to answer the question. So I would say that the team just doesn't want people being penalized for spam, when they were just trying to help the bad questioner.

Comment: What a memorable domain name

Comment: Your comment made me remember, @RetoKoradi, that [spam flags are apparently auto-dismissed when the post is deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175420/). That implies that flagging and _skipping_ in the review queue would be best.

Comment: Spam flags can have severe impact on a user's reputation (a negative 100 rep, IIRC, if the post is identified as spam), and there's a tendency for users to flag posts as "spam" that actually aren't according to SO's definition of the term. Perhaps that's the reason why it's not available in the LQRQ?

Comment: Problem with your first sentence: HAM is also delicious grilled with a slice of pineapple, possibly even moreso than spam.  :-p

Comment: A logical fallacy, @BenVoigt. That both delicious(X) and delicious(Y) are true does not allow us to conclude that isa(x, X) might be false and isa(x, Y) true. Nonetheless, I agree -- I'd rather have the ham, too.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: The fallacy is in assuming that `spam is delicious; delicious, therefore spam`  You're right that a failure of the argument doesn't prove the conclusion false, but there's more needed to prove it true.  And a single counter-example does prove the conclusion false.

Comment: @BenVoigt What happens if we don't have any pineapple?

Comment: @IstvanChung: That would be.... very serious indeed.  I sure hope that the Ebola pandemic does not affect our pineapple supplies.

Comment: FWIW I saw this too... got out of review mode and flagged it spam.  **Feature request: Flag as spam from review mode**

Comment: Indeed maybe edit this post as Paul suggests and add a feature request tag?

Comment: @Lundin: That request [has already been made](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191860/include-the-option-to-flag-posts-as-spam-in-the-low-quality-queue), as [Patrick Hofman pointed out](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274496/what-am-i-supposed-to-do-with-a-piece-of-spam-that-i-review-in-the-low-quality-q?noredirect=1#comment105991_274496).

Answer (score 13):

I wasn't going to go out on a limb but since [one of the answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274679/839601) suggested...

> **This was not spam**...

...I would like to address that.

Links are *unsolicited*. Not by the asker mind you - I can't get into their head and tell what they really want - by *Stack Exchange*. It's a [widely announced and long established norm here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/144581/165773) that link-only answers are not what Stack Exchange wants.

Now, pay attention that [post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0Hll.png) is entirely devoid of answering [the question asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12782034/839601) and contains only link to advertised site. That makes it just what you feel it is, *unsolicited electronic message* - exactly how spam is defined in [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spamming).

Answer (score 10):

It is a link to a site with commercial interests, which has little or no relevance to the topic. So it is spam, and not just a link-only answer (which would have been reason enough to delete the answer anyhow).

The review system is limited: you cannot flag from inside it, possibly because reviewing low-quality posts is actually the task of handling flags. So if you would only flag the post without taking any review action, you'll merely hand the problem to someone else.

What you should do is to delete vote. Pick "no reason" or "link-only answer" - the reason isn't all that important in this case, we just want the crap to be gone from the site asap. But since it is spam, moderators may have to take further actions beyond deleting posts. Therefore you should also go to the post and manually flag as spam. (Same thing goes for posts that are offensive, a diamond mod needs to be notified by manually flagging the post.)

Indeed this is a bit strange, there should be a spam option in the low quality review. But until someone implements such a feature, flag manually in addition to your delete vote.

Comment: Can you square your answer with my last paragraph? I believe that the spam flag will be dismissed without a moderator ever seeing it if the post is deleted via the queue.

Comment: @JoshCaswell In that case, it would seem that the whole system is broken. The review audits constantly encourage you to quietly delete obvious spam posts. Between the lines, the review audit say that the most important thing is to get the spam away from the site. Because there is indeed no "delete because it is spam" option.

Comment: I disagree that you should delete vote. The system handles spam deletions separately from ordinary ones, and information which would be useful to moderators may be lost if it is deleted for being a crappy regular post as opposed to irrelevant advertisement.

Comment: @Lundin: The "offensive" and "spam"-flags are *special*: Instead of *just* going to the mods for processing, 6 of them also do it all by themselves. Which means that reason doesn't fly. Though maybe there are too many mis-flags then?... (puzzled about the real reason)

Answer (score -22):

This was not spam. It was a link-only answer to someone's own work *on the topic of the question* and therefore inappropriate, but it's not unsolicited links to porn or a viagra merchant. There is no need to flag this post; simply delete it and move on.

Comment: yeah sure. The fact that answerer advertises their database as ["cheap"](http://i.stack.imgur.com/B0Hll.png) is a sure sign that it's not spam. Would they say "our database is expensive", that would be a different matter

Comment: @gnat Are you seriously suggesting that this post is spam because the person selling a good has decided not to advertise it as "expensive"???

Comment: are you seriously suggesting that being a link-only answer to matched question saves it from (also) being a spam. You know, this opens a whole new horizon for spammers. Searching Google for questions that match the goods to advertise has never been as easy as now

Comment: I think gnat was actually being sarcastic there... your notion that the answer is not spam does not seem to be widely supported based on the votes of your answer. The relevancy of the link is very questionable, and spam is not alwys about porn or viagra. It hasn't been that simple since the nineties.

Comment: @gnat: _"are you seriously suggesting that being a link-only answer to matched question saves it from (also) being a spam"_ No, of course not. I am suggesting that being a link-only answer does not automatically make it spam. In fact, it's not just a suggestion.

Comment: High quality nike shoes can helpful for racers of all weights and orbits, cheaply. https://www.special-nikes-for-stackoverflow-racers.com