# Add "Flag as spam" button to Low quality posts review panel

Tags: feature-request, low-quality-posts, spam

Sometimes, when reviewing Low Quality Posts, I find genuinely spamtastic or offensive posts that should be flagged. I mean, literally, commercial advertisements, link-only questions or answers to for-pay software sites, and a few profanity-filled rants posing as questions.

Instead of having to

1. stop my review flow,
2. click to open the question,
3. click on the *flag* link,
4. click review,
5. go back to what I was reviewing,

wouldn't it be a good idea to have the *flag as spam* and *flag as offensive* links available directly in the review panel?

Comment: You shouldn't be flagging stuff that's just crappy as spam, you should only be flagging clear cases of (literal) spam. Is that what you meant? 'Very low quality' is for toxic waste that someone needs to put out of its misery quickly. 'Spam' helps train our spam / abuse mitigation systems, there's a _very_ big difference there.

Comment: I would assume (though the OP should clarify) that this is referring to actual cases of spam in the queue (for example audits, or not-yet-deleted spam mistakenly flagged as low-quality/not-an-answer instead of flagged as spam). Like this case: [What am I supposed to do with a piece of spam that I review in the Low Quality queue?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274496/what-am-i-supposed-to-do-with-a-piece-of-spam-that-i-review-in-the-low-quality-q)

Comment: I would say yes, but they should also be **red colored** so that it is clear that abusing them is a bad thing.

Comment: Edit note: This post is a **feature request**, not a discussion question, so I edited it to firm up the language and try to make the best case possible for this hassle-saving feature.

Comment: @TimPost Maybe it's just the sites I'm on, but I see real spam in the LQP review queue fairly often. [This is one such from the review queue just now](http://travel.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/29388)

Comment: What happened with this request? To have a spam option would be helpful, especially since there is an option "this is a link only question (and not spam)" and every low-quality review seem to lead to a deleted spam post.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I encounter a genuine spam case about, I would guess, one out of every 60 VLQ reviews on SO. It's obnoxious to have to stop reviewing, open the question, flag, leave a comment directing other reviewers to flag as spam but not vote to delete*, then get back into reviewing.

It sure would be nice to have spam as a deletion option. The obvious concern would be improper [over]use within review. I suggest two possible ways to mitigate that:

1. Add "spam" as an option to the delete menu in VLQ, but require an extra confirmation step if it's selected as the reason.

   - +Easy to use, understand and implement.
   - +The dialog can include a nice concise explanation of what is spam and how it's different from a link only answer.
   - -The obvious choice for extra confirmation is a modal, and any way you cut it it will still be slower than the other choices.
   - -Let's be honest, the extra visibility from right there next to the delete button (I'm envisioning spam as the last option) means there *will* be false positives.
2. Enable flagging on posts in the VLQQ. Abridge the menu so that choices which don't make sense or otherwise shouldn't be accessible aren't.

   - +Reduces the likelihood of an influx of unwarranted spam flags, because it's not on the queue's delete menu.
   - +Easy to extend to other odd edge cases, such as offensive (I don't think this is necessary, but it conceivably could be in the future and is called out in the question).
   - -A spam flag cast ought to count as a review. Implementing this is probably difficult and adds significant complexity to the queue's inner workings.
   - -Reviewers who aren't experienced enough to know about spam vs. VLQ (or even experienced ones who don't notice that flagging has become an option), are left out, because flagging from within VLQ isn't intuitive. They won't learn anything (contrasted with seeing a shiny new "spam" item in the dialog) and will continue to vote to delete as normal.

*My understanding is that if the post is deleted as a result of reviews, it won't get properly logged as spam by the system. I'd love to be wrong about this, but if it's accurate, perhaps a reasonable stopgap would be to raise a flag for a moderator to review the post if it's deleted as a result of VLQ reviews but at the same time accrued 2 or 3 spam flags. Which of course doesn't scale...

Comment: I'm for option 1.  We already have "link-only answer (and not spam)", so we can put "spam" right below it.

Comment: 2017 and still nothing happened. This should really be implemented.