# Spam Audits in the Low Quality Posts - But spam shouldn't be deleted

Tags: discussion, review-queues, spam

I came across [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/9703378) in the Low Quality Posts review queue. It seemed a lot like an audit, but in case it wasn't an audit I knew I should go to the post page and flag the answer as spam so it could be picked up by moderators.

Obviously the post was gone as it was indeed an audit. So I went back to the pack and it occurred to me that the audit would force to me to click "Recommend Deletion" as Looks OK and Edit were both false. However *none* of these are actually good reactions to spam. Spam is supposed to be kept for moderators to find, so they can make sure a spammer isn't going undetected.

Surely this means that having these as audits encourages the wrong response to spam and will cause people to try removing spam instead of deleting it? Surely spam can at least be excluded from the audits.

Comment: Mods can actually go after deleted posts as well.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Oh, that's true. But if you just delete then they wont be notified that there's spam there.

Comment: I suppose the best reaction is open link in new tab --> Flag as spam on the post itself (comment if desired) --> "Recommend Deletion" in the review (no comment needed).  Yeah the VLQ queue doesn't handle the spam case very elegantly.

Comment: Related: [What am I supposed to do with a piece of spam that I review in the low quality queue?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274496)

Comment: Also related: ["Add “Flag as spam” button to Low quality posts review panel"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275173/add-flag-as-spam-button-to-low-quality-posts-review-panel)

Comment: I'm just curious: why this question was considered spam? I agree it is a poor quality question and even off-topic, but why spam?

Comment: @GustavoStraube It's the answer that was deleted as spam ("answer not found" behind the audit link).

Comment: And in case you can't read it, the answer was: "I like to play Clash of Clans and I use <spam link> Now you will know why some clans are so strong! (random letters)"

Comment: As an addition (another answer, but also spam): I clicked onto "Edit" hoping to get an option to mark this as spam. And immediately received the warning, that this was a test and I failed. IMHO that encourages to select a *wrong* action: Suggesting a non-spam deletion.

Comment: Here’s [another such audit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/15063364)… the answer itself has long been deleted and I knew that the system wanted me to “Recommend Deletion”…

Comment: I found another [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/19994132).

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374043/792066