# How to flag a ChatGPT answer in an audit

Tags: support, chatgpt, ethics

I went through the audit section **"low quality answers"** and the following came up:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/34846165

Since it is not really the answer for the question and this really, really looks like a generic ChatGPT answer (I have no proof), how should I handle this? It doesn't fit any of the reasons to choose from in the audit when clicking "recommend deletion":

[image]

A second reason to delete is his advertising-link for a programming page.

Comment: That should have been flagged as spam (It had a link to an external site that didn't seem to be relevant).

Comment: In terms of the link I totally agree but I wonder about his text-answer.

Comment: @Cerbrus If I would have stumbled upon it crawling through stackoverflow: Yes. But I was in "low quality answers" and couldn't find a solution there.

Comment: Looks like this is an audit since the real post has been deleted. The expected approach is to open the post directly and mod-flag it, but since this is an audit, then selecting recommend deletion (any reason) should be okay, or just skip it.

Comment: This is a weakness in the queue design. See also [Spam Audits in the Low Quality Posts - But spam shouldn't be deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307201/6083675)

Comment: This seems like spam, in which case that's probably a more severe offense than posting a ChatGPT answer. Spam should always get flagged as spam - review or not. It should not just get silently deleted without raising the spam flag. Nor flagged as low quality/naa. Nor flagged as in need of moderator attention unless it's a special case. If you aren't certain what to flag something as, then ask in to SO close vote review chat.

Comment: see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422338/11107541

Comment: If the answer is correct why would you even bother if ChatGPT authored it??? It just does not make sense at all.  Banning GPT/LLMs answers is as clever as people fighting weaving machines in 18th century.

Let alone that there are bots on Github that can give you 99% correct answer in minutes.

Comment: @matcheek: Use ChatGPT and not Stackoverflow then. PS: Answer was too generic and didn't solve the problem by any means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Credit goes to @Andrew T.

> Looks like this is an audit since the real post has been deleted. The
> expected approach is to open the post directly and mod-flag it, but
> since this is an audit, then selecting recommend deletion (any reason)
> should be okay, or just skip it.

Why is this correct:

- understood that it is about an audit function.
- explained the correct approach

Comment: "open the post directly and mod-flag it" No need for that in case it is spam - just spam flag it.