# How to "resurrect" a feature request

Tags: discussion, old-questions, feature-request-process

Back in 2014, I posted [this 'feature request'](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275173/add-flag-as-spam-button-to-low-quality-posts-review-panel). Back then, I was trying to be very active on SO... but since then, work and life have driven me away from the review queues.

Anyway, the post was (I think) well-received, but it has not been implemented. I'm not complaining, but I'd like to know if there's a way to "resurrect" the topic:

1. Should I create a new post referencing my original proposal?
2. Should I flag it for moderators attention?

I don't know if this may apply to other posts, but I think that there should be a way to ask for a follow-up on proposals.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317708/bringing-attention-to-old-meta-questions-when-you-cant-edit and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364131/how-to-renew-an-old-feature-request

Comment: But why? It's in the list already. If developers have it ignored, why would they not do it again? I am guessing that **every** post tagged with `feature-request` and `bug` has to pass some kind of moderation and then it's in developers backlog somewhere or maybe they use meta directly as backlog. You just have to wait. Don't do anything, unless you want non-developers attention. If it's a very needed feature, then time is working for you, don't worry.

Comment: @Sinatr I haven't look at the mentioned feature request yet but to me at least it makes sense.  The site has changed *a lot* over the past 4 years.  A feature request that would be detrimental, unwelcome, or unfeasible back in 2014 might be well received today.  I'm not saying that's the case - just that's it's possible and Barranka seems interested in what one should do if they feel that might be the case.

Comment: @Dason Thank you. That's exactly what I think: if it has a chance to be considered a good idea, I'd like to bump it back to attention... of course it may not look like a good idea to everybody... but it may be good to some. Anyway, thank you again